# how to crop image after capturing from camera through intent : Android

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to get image capture image from camera and want to crop it by android gallery's crop 
activity to a fixed aspect ratio and a fixed size.

this code is for gallery and i want as it for camera

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Answer (score 0):

public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri)
    {
        /*Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);*/

```
    // System.out.println("cropCapturedImage picUri=" + picUri);
    // call the standard crop action intent
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    // indicate image type and Uri of image
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    // set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    // indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    // indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    // retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}
```

send the uri of the image captured from camera